# Set HTTP Referrer from the server?

Tags: php, redirect, header

is there a way to send the http referrer from the server instead of the browser?

Here is what I have tried so far

```
    if ($download_result['redirect'])
    {
        header('Referer: http://torcache.net/torrent/DD157829553E81D3C513D93420624942FFA48D99.torrent');
        header('Server: nginx/1.3.0');
        header('Content-Type: application/x-bittorrent');
        header('Content-Encoding: gzip');
        header('Content-Length: 10767');
        header('Location: ' . $download_result['url2']);
    }
    }
```

I need to set the referer agent because using Torcache first goes to a html page before actually downloading the torrent cache; this makes it annoying as you have to click on the back button to go back to the website after d.l; After seeing the GET headers that were sent, I wanted to fake the http referrer agent so that it skips the html page and gets the cache

Answer (score 4):

No, the server cannot force the client to send a particular HTTP Referer value.

Comment: That is unless he wants to cURL the page himself and then send the results to the client.

Comment: Then *the server* is doing the request, which does not sound like what he wants to do.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can do the GET request using cURL like this.

```
header('Content-type: application/x-bittorrent');
$ch = curl_init('http://torcache.net/torrent/DD157829553E81D3C513D93420624942FFA48D99.torrent');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, null);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);                                                                 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-bittorrent','Referer: http://torcache.net/torrent/DD157829553E81D3C513D93420624942FFA48D99.torrent')); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://torcache.net/torrent/DD157829553E81D3C513D93420624942FFA48D99.torrent'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"gzip");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```